# C++ sizeof with virtual inheritance 64 bit

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand how `sizeof` exactly behaves in a 64 bit system.

Most of the questions here about this topic were about 32 bit systems, where things aren't as tricky (to me at least).

I know I shouldn't really mess with those stuff because it's system dependent, however I need to get a better understanding of what's going on here.

First case:

```
template<typename T>
void show(const T *p, std::string s)
{
    printf("%-3s: address = 0x%010x, size = %2d\n", 
            s.c_str(), p, sizeof(T));
}

struct A {
   int x_a;
    void showA() const { show(this, "A"); }
};

struct B1 : virtual A {
   int x_b1;
    void showB1() const { show(this, "B1"); }
};

struct B2 : virtual A {
   int x_b2;
    void showB2() const { show(this, "B2"); }
};

struct C : B1, B2 { 
   int x_c;
    void showC() const { show(this, "C"); }
};

void f(const C& c) {
   c.showC();
   c.showB1();
   c.showA();    
   c.showB2();
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
   f(C());
   return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
C  : address = 0x00e21966b0, size = 40                                                                                                        
B1 : address = 0x00e21966b0, size = 16                                                                                                        
A  : address = 0x00e21966d0, size =  4                                                                                                        
B2 : address = 0x00e21966c0, size = 16
```

Now, if I add another field with type `int*`, the output changes to:

```
C  : address = 0x0069106460, size = 48                                                                                                        
B1 : address = 0x0069106460, size = 32                                                                                                        
A  : address = 0x0069106480, size = 16                                                                                                        
B2 : address = 0x0069106470, size = 32
```

Here's how I see things:

The memory structure is supposed to look something like this:

```
*B1 | *B2 | C | A
```

Where * represents a pointer to `A`

At the first case, `B1` has a pointer with size 8, `A` with size 4 and an `int` with size 4. It seems like no alignment is done here. At the second case though, instead of the size being 8+12+4, the result is 32. It seems like both B1 and A are aligned in some way, even though first none of them was aligned.

I simply can't understand those results, and why this happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: An `int` will be aligned on a 4-byte boundary, with padding added as needed (none in this case).  An `int *` will be aligned on an 8-byte boundary in a 64 bit build, with padding inserted as needed.

Comment: Both `B1` and `B2` contain space for an instance of `A`, as well as the pointer to `A`. Each class may be used standalone, in which case it would need its own copy. In `C`, only one of these two reserved spaces actually contains a valid `A` instance - but the empty space is still there.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Could you explain why in second case we get sizeof(B1)=32?

Comment: @EL_9 remember that the class representation need not contain a *pointer* to a sub-object; all it needs to contain is an *offset* to a sub-object, which may be smaller than a pointer.  If using VC++, explore this using an internal switch: https://ofekshilon.com/2010/11/07/d1reportallclasslayout-dumping-object-memory-layout/

Comment: Add some extra calls like `show(&x_a, "x_A")` and you will have a more complete picture of the final layout. You can also swap the order of the added pointer with the `int` and check the effect. Essentially 8 + 12 + 4 will give 32 because you really have `(8 + (4 + _4_ + 8) + 4) + _4_` where `_4_` are added for alignment of part and of the whole. If you put the pointer first in B2, you will probaly get 24 instead of 32: `8 + (8 + 4) + 4`.

Comment: @Phil1970 Then how do we get 16 bytes at the first print? I can even see that B by itself needs 16 bytes...

Comment: Suppose you have padding after each member. Thus your struct is: (a) int, (b) padding, (c) pointer and (d) padding. (a) is 4 bytes, (c) is 8 bytes. (c) must be aligned on 8 bytes boudary, thus (b) is 4 bytes. (a) + (b) + (c) + (d) must be a multiple of 8 since largest member need 8 bytes alignment. (a) + (b) + (c) give 16, so (d) can be 0. **Be aware that all of this is deductions from values you got with your printing.** Other compilers might use different rules or ordering.